# Run different functions based on positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

So basicially I have two functions. First function runs in case of I check a radio button that comes **before** the currently checked one. And the second function runs in case of I check a radio button that comes **after** the currently checked one. How could this be done?

```
<input type="radio" id="a" name="radio">
<label for="a">A</label>

<input type="radio" id="b" name="radio" checked>
<label for="b">B</label>

<input type="radio" id="c" name="radio">
<label for="c">C</label>

<input type="radio" id="d" name="radio">
<label for="d">D</label>  



  $("input[name='radio']").change(function(){

    if {
    // do something
    }

    if {
    // do something
    }

  });
```

Comment: Save the index of the red dot. If the clicked radios index is lower, run function one, if it's bigger, run function two. Still, it sounds a bit like finnicky design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `index` of the input before, if its less then fire the before function, else fire the after. then reset the current index to the now index.

```js
var currentIndex = $("input[name='radio']:checked").index('input');
$("input[name='radio']").change(function() {
  var index = $(this).index('input');
  if (index < currentIndex) {
    console.log('before');
  } else {
    console.log('after');
  }
  currentIndex = index;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" id="a" name="radio">
<label for="a">A</label>

<input type="radio" id="b" name="radio" checked>
<label for="b">B</label>

<input type="radio" id="c" name="radio">
<label for="c">C</label>

<input type="radio" id="d" name="radio">
<label for="d">D</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the comments, keep track of the index's.
Store in a var an match against the changed checkbox's index

```
var cindex = $('input[name=radio]:checked').index('input');
$("input[name='radio']").change(function(){
   var thisindex = $(this).index('input');
   if ( thisindex < cindex ) {
       // clicked a previous checkbox
   } else {
       // clicked a next checkbox
   }
   // update the cindex;
   cindex = thisindex;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable which stores the previous checked button ID and compare it with the current one. Since 'a', 'b', 'c' are normal strings, you can compare them using default **<** and **>** operators:

```
  var prevID = $('input[name=radio]:checked').attr('id');

  $("input[name='radio']").change(function()
  {
    var curID = $(this).attr('id');

    if (curID < prevID) {
        alert("Before");
    }

    else if (curID > prevID) {
        alert("After");
    }
    prevID = curID;

  });
```